# How to customize a subdomain for an azure api app?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I would like to know if there is a way to configure a subdomain for an azure api app that I recently published.

The current url provided from azure looks `like https://microsoft-apiappd2c35ca5dbc343bca7543041467c2b32.azurewebsites.net` and I haven't found a way to configure a subdomain like myapi.mycompany.com as I can do it with the websites.

Comment: If there is not a way, should I publish my app as a website? I'm wide open for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize it on the API app host. To find that, open the API App blade and on the settings find the "API app host" and click it. On the new blade that will open, click on "All Settings" and then "Custom domains and SSL".

Just keep in mind that this likely will only be valid during the preview and might change in the future.

Comment: I did that, but now get an error. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330649/azure-api-app-no-apiapp-installed-that-can-handle-forward-request-to-https-my