# Azure API App "No ApiApp installed that can handle forward request to https://my.customdomain.com"

Tags: azure-api-apps

I added a custom domain name for an Azure API App (actually on the underlying `API app host`).

The `https://microsoft-apiappXXXXXXXX.azurewebsites.net/ address still works but the custom domain yields the following error in the browser:

```
<Error>
  <Message>
     No ApiApp installed that can handle forward request to https://my.customdomain.com/
   </Message>
</Error>
```

I've configured a custom SSL certificate, but with or without it, I get the same issue (minus the SSL warning when the custom SSL is not configured). HTTP access just issues a 302 Redirect to HTTPS.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's unfortunate.. Let me check a bit around and see if I can find some info, I haven't seen this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known limitation of the preview bits when using custom domains. When I replied on the original thread of yours I didn't realize that, my apologies.

It's on our backlog and the team is working hard to get this implemented. It's a very common scenario so I don't think it will take much time (maybe a couple of weeks if everything goes ok) but I don't have an exact ETA to share at this point. I'll update this thread once it's live, it shouldn't be long.

You can find a list of known issues [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f8b42f2-ac0d-48b8-a35e-3b4934e1c25e/api-app-known-issues?forum=AzureAPIApps), we will update it to include this as well.

Comment: That's a shame, but thanks for the information. I'll monitor that MS forum post.

Comment: Hello @Panagiotis - I just hit this one. Any chance of an update 3 weeks on? If we need it within a week should we make alternate arrangements? Thanks! :)

Comment: @AlexAngas Let me check and get back to you. It was around the corner but I just want to make sure I don't make foul promises :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKefalidis I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Yeah - this is really, really important.  Any meaningful use of the API will require external domain usage.  Really trying to leverage api app capability but is dead in the water without it.

Comment: @drewid I agree, yes. We're doing the best we can to make this happen. The fix is not far away at this point. It should be out really soon.

Comment: @PanagiotisKefalidis, is this feature in now? It's almost 3 months since the last comment here.

Comment: Im looking to get this working too currently - any update on this?